# How to take RTMP AMF frame by frame metadata and insert it into the saved MP4 video file?

Tags: metadata, mp4, rtmp, wowza

I can't seem to find a way in Wowza or any other solution like nginx-rtmp-module to take a live stream's RTMP metadata and insert it into the specific frames of the MP4 saved file.

Maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way, but our live streaming app only allows the broadcaster to post comments/feedback and we want to make sure the viewers see those comments on the exact frame that the comment was made on by the broadcaster. We tried having the two being separated where the video was streamed via wowza and the comments sent to clients via PubNub but there is just to much variance on when the comments show up.

The only way I can think of is to include the broadcaster comments inside metadate for the specific frame the comment was made. Then we'd be guaranteed to have the comment show up in the right place.

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't know anything about Wowza or mp4 programming but can you tie the timeline of the video to the comments from PubNub? You could retrieve messages from PubNub 100 messages at a time (retrieve the next 100 when you get to message 75 of the current set or use some time based algorithm for getting next set of comments). Then as the video plays, use the video timeline to display the messages that match that frame(s).

Comment: @CraigConover Thanks for the comment. The tricky part is there can be significant latency. So the broadcaster could be at time 30s in the video, viewer 1 could be at 15s and viewer 3 could be at 9s. When the broadcaster posts a comment at 30s, we don't want to immediately show it to viewer 1 and 2 since they are behind. And getting the exact latency of the stream is not reliable, so having the comment data and video data separated has been too unreliable.

Comment: Right, so you are just grabbing history at (up to) 100 messages at a time and displaying them by matching the timetoken with the time of the timeline of the video. To optimize (instead of pulling history), you can subscribe to the broadcaster's chat channel and receive the messages in reatlime and do not show the message until it is time to do so for each individual client. Sara Haider explains how Periscope did this with PubNub: http://nerds.airbnb.com/building-periscope-for-android/

Comment: @CraigConover thanks for the reply! Yes, we've seen that video and that's what convinced us to use PubNub (which we love BTW). Our problem is we allow the broadcaster to actually start/stop/pause/restart the stream and we combine the stream into one file after pauses/restarts. This happens pretty regularly, and it makes our lives more difficult because we have to store all the pause lengths and apply them across the board to all offsets, etc. We can get close doing this, but not perfect. And we felt if there was a way to uniquely identify a frame in an h.264 stream we could just use that.

Comment: Oh good - well, I guess my assistance ends here :) Please post your solution if you figure it out before someone else.

Comment: I had a somewhat similar issue when implementing comments for our iphone client. I/we solved it by putting ID3 tags into the video stream (https://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?35346-ID3-tags-injection-gt-cupertino-Live-Stream) that essentially were very simple time-stamps and we used Faye (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faye_(web_messaging_protocol) to get the messages. So the messages were real-time and I just saved them up (as they came in) and then replayed them when the appropriate time-stamp came through on the ID3 tag.

Comment: How are you recording the mp4 file? Are you doing so using the Wowza Manager? If so, you should be able to select Record data as an option in the recorder, and it will include the metadata that is present from the live stream to the recorded mp4 file.